# Get data into Master sheet from multiple sheets of same spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Sheets -> Google Sheets (not PC excel)

I have multiple data to import into a Master sheet from multiple sheets within the same spreadsheet. So I don't want to use (for example) `=Sheet1!$A$23` or `IMPORTRANGE` (as it's the same sheet and again I have to hard code the sheet names)

[image]

As the data is a lot, and sheet names have spaces too, so I need a formula/function which picks the sheet name from the column cell and pick the data address i.e. `X1` where data is available in the multiple sheets

NOTE: I can hard code the data cell (i.e. `$A$23`), as it would be the same in my case. But can't hard code the sheet names. It would be great if the address of the sheet name and data cell of that sheet can be picked from cells.

NOTE: Data to get from the multiple sheets are simple amounts, like expenses, as mentioned in the header.

Explanation: In multiple monthly expense sheets, some data cells are just values (like year, month, etc.) and some have functions like `=SUM(B23:Z23)` showing the total expense of that month which I want to bring/copy/show in the Master sheet.

Is there any solution available for this problem?

Comment: yes this will be possible. however, not without knowing how the data that will be imported is structured. are you able to provide screenshot or table visualisation how the data is structured in the source sheets. also, can you please explain is this for excel (which version) or google sheets. because solutions for one may not be suitable for the other.

Comment: Here is a blank sample spreadsheet created specifically for this question.  If you use it to create a sample of the scenario you're describing, i think folks will be able to show you how to do it.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JCbhZG-_keM3J2PHfSbddrNe87Tnaefyhu8sVHXcgDM/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in X3

```
=INDIRECT("'"&text(Y3,"MMM yyyy")&"'!"&$X$1)
```

see [indirect()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works if the data cell contains a value (without formula) is written (like date, month, etc.). 

But if the data cell contains a formula like `=SUM(B23:Z23)`, then it doesn't return any value. It stays blank. While it should return the SUM value in the Master sheet

Comment: Is it a question or a remark? It's difficult to understand without a copy of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Both you can say question and remark too. As the image shows that expenses which are written in each month's sheet, and in `A23` of each sheet are the sum of expenses of that month. And now I want to bring that sum from all sheets to the Master sheet

Comment: ok, sorry, I undestand, I have changed my answer